# Executable gem - Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I am trying to create an executable gem on windows machine. But i am not sure how do make the file executable in windows? Is there any way i can create the same on windows? Here is what i did so far: created a file and then right click and update the permission to read and execute. But its not working. I am keeping this file under bin folder as mentioned " [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) " in the link

Comment: Add the file mentioned in the above link, but i am not able to execute via command line. My executable file has just one puts sentence for now... just want to say "hi" in the console...

Comment: Have you tried executing your gem file in a `.bat` file?

Comment: my idea is not to wrap gem inside a bat file and execute that. let me give an example: If i install Cucumber gem and then go to console and type cucumber it will execute the cucumber gem. Hows that working.? Was looking at the cucumber code and found that there is bin folder which has the executable command. If you look at the link i have mentioned in my previous post, that has the Linux implementation details, not windows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gem is not executable itself, it is a bundled collection of Ruby scripts and other files which can be executable. You can compare it with a Zip file.
The purpose is to easily distribute your projects tot other computers.
When you `gem install` the gem and require the gem in a script then you can use what the gem has to offer.

It is possible to execute the scripts and executable files when you use the full path in your console or when the path is included in the Windows path environtment variable. Sometimes a .bat or .cmd (in Windows) is provided that can be called but it just executes some other Ruby scripts.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that completely. I have installed cucumber gem and if i go to command line and type cucumber, it execute the command. I am thinking that's an executable gem. My intention is to execute my gem code from command line

Comment: such a gem includes a .bat of .cmd file that does something, eg create a new project, the gem itself is not executable, the .bat just executes a .rb file that is extracted out of the cucumber gem.  Look for a cucumber.bat file somewhere in your path, I use the tool search everything to look for files

Comment: Yes, Now i can see cucumber bat file inside the ruby bin class. Since the Ruby bin path is already there in path, it just execute the cucumber command. Thanks everyone for helping me to understand the executable gem concept. :)

Comment: But that file is automatically generated by rubygems. I can see a comment on the top of the file "This file was generated by RubyGems." So i think we dont need to create this file manually, ruby gems automatically handle that, right? In my case, it is not happening. So can someone please tell me how exactly this happening ?

Comment: see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Installer.html#method-i-generate_windows_script